# Capture entire window with winapi

Tags: java, windows, winapi, capture

I am using winapi to capture the window of opened software applications in Java.
This function below captures the window of the software application and returns the image.

```
public static BufferedImage capture(HWND hWnd) {
   HDC hdcWindow = User32.INSTANCE.GetDC(hWnd);
   HDC hdcMemDC = GDI32.INSTANCE.CreateCompatibleDC(hdcWindow);
   RECT bounds = new RECT();
   RECT bounds1 = new RECT();
   User32Extra.INSTANCE.GetWindowRect(hWnd, bounds);
   User32Extra.INSTANCE.GetClientRect(hWnd, bounds1);

   int extraGap = (bounds.right-bounds.left-bounds1.right);
   int width = bounds.right-bounds.left-extraGap;
   int height = bounds.bottom-bounds.top-extraGap ;
   HBITMAP hBitmap = GDI32.INSTANCE.CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcWindow, width, height);

   HANDLE hOld = GDI32.INSTANCE.SelectObject(hdcMemDC, hBitmap);
   GDI32Extra.INSTANCE.BitBlt(hdcMemDC,0, 0, width, height, hdcWindow, bounds.left+bounds1.right-bounds.right+extraGap, bounds.top+bounds1.bottom-bounds.bottom+extraGap, WinGDIExtra.MERGECOPY);
   GDI32.INSTANCE.SelectObject(hdcMemDC, hOld);

   BITMAPINFO bmi = new BITMAPINFO();
   bmi.bmiHeader.biWidth = width;
   bmi.bmiHeader.biHeight = -height;
   bmi.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
   bmi.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 32;
   bmi.bmiHeader.biCompression = WinGDI.BI_RGB;
   Memory buffer = new Memory(width * height * 4);
   GDI32.INSTANCE.GetDIBits(hdcWindow, hBitmap, 0, height, buffer, bmi, WinGDI.DIB_RGB_COLORS);

   BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
   image.setRGB(0, 0, width, height, buffer.getIntArray(0, width * height), 0, width);

   System.out.println(GDI32.INSTANCE.DeleteObject(hBitmap));
   System.out.println(GDI32.INSTANCE.DeleteObject(hdcMemDC));
   System.out.println(User32.INSTANCE.ReleaseDC(hWnd, hdcWindow));

   return image;
}
```

The image captured has some errors like:-

1. This is the image of Flash Builder window with Eclipse Title Bar.

   [image: Flash Builder Image with Eclipse title Bar]
2. This is the image of Chrome Browser without Window buttons.

   [image: Chrome window without window buttons]
3. This is the image of file browser with Eclipse title bar.

   [image: File Browser window with]
4. Sometimes the title bar is not captured in the image.

Do you have any idea why, and how I could solve this problem? Anything wrong in my code?

Comment: Try `(WinGDIExtra.CAPTUREBLT | WinGDIExtra.SRCCOPY)` instead of `WinGDIExtra.MERGECOPY`

Comment: @barmak-shemirani I have tried that, even thought I am getting the same output. `CAPTUREBLT` value is not present in the following link http://www.cs.uofs.edu/~beidler/Ada/win32/win32-wingdi.html. can you please confirm the value please. I am using this `public DWORD CAPTUREBLT = new DWORD(0x00CC0020 | 0x40000000);`

Comment: Yes your values are correct. The problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Try `GetDesktopWindow()` to capture the entire desktop window. Otherwise I think that's as good as it gets for capturing individual windows.

Comment: If I capture desktop window, there are some problems like overlapping of other window on target window. I have done that but my task is to capture specific window.

Comment: I tried your method with C++ and couldn't do any better. I think the only way to do it is with `GetDesktopWindow`. You can use `SetForegroundWindow`, `GetWindowRect` etc. to overcome the problem with overlap. I can post C++ code for that if you like, maybe you can post a C++ question. By the way, what is the above code anyway, is it Swing?

Comment: I am presently capturing images with those methods only..
Java with winapi...